# Exclude OR Rule out OR else?

Tags: medical

Rachel often gets really bad headaches. She is afraid of having a brain tumor. I know that she does not have other symptoms, which are common in brain tumor so I do not think it is likely that she has a brain tumor. But I would like to reassure her completely. I would like to say to her, that a brain tumor can be *excluded/ruled out* by a brain MRI. Which is more understandable for her?

Answer (score 1):

In your exact phrasing, it would be more natural to say, "ruled out." However, one could say any of the following:

*A brain tumor could be ruled out by an MRI.*

*An MRI can exclude the possibility of a brain tumor.*

*The MRI allowed for us to eliminate a brain tumor as a potential explanation for your symptoms.*

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I really appreciate your detailed and more formal versions too. :)